# Installing tf-nightly-gpu-2.0-preview on Google Colab

Tags: tensorflow, google-colaboratory

I would like to test the new TensorFlow 2.0 preview on [Colab](https://colab.research.google.com) with GPU support but, after installing TensorFlow using `!pip install tf-nightly-gpu-2.0-preview` on a cell, when I import the package I get the error: `ImportError: libcublas.so.10.0: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory` which points to some misalignment with the pre-installed CUDA version on the platform.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The solution is to re-install CUDA 10.0 on Colab by the following instructions:

```
!wget https://developer.nvidia.com/compute/cuda/10.0/Prod/local_installers/cuda-repo-ubuntu1604-10-0-local-10.0.130-410.48_1.0-1_amd64 -O cuda-repo-ubuntu1604-10-0-local-10.0.130-410.48_1.0-1_amd64.deb
!dpkg -i cuda-repo-ubuntu1604-10-0-local-10.0.130-410.48_1.0-1_amd64.deb
!apt-key add /var/cuda-repo-10-0-local-10.0.130-410.48/7fa2af80.pub
!apt-get update
!apt-get install cuda
!pip install tf-nightly-gpu-2.0-preview
```

After executing the previous commands in a cell, you can import and test the TensorFlow 2.0 preview with GPU support:

```
import tensorflow as tf
print(tf.__version__)
```

Answer (score 1):

Change Noteboot Setting to use Hardware accelerator
set on GPU
after that run

```
!pip install tf-nightly
import tensorflow as tf
print(tf.__version__)
```