# TensorFlow 2 not show the version in colab google and windows 10

Tags: python, tensorflow, tensorflow2.0

I install the TensorFlow version 2 in google colab:

`!wget https://developer.nvidia.com/compute/cuda/10.0/Prod/local_installers/cuda-repo-ubuntu1604-10-0-local-10.0.130-410.48_1.0-1_amd64 -O cuda-repo-ubuntu1604-10-0-local-10.0.130-410.48_1.0-1_amd64.deb
!dpkg -i cuda-repo-ubuntu1604-10-0-local-10.0.130-410.48_1.0-1_amd64.deb
!apt-key add /var/cuda-repo-10-0-local-10.0.130-410.48/7fa2af80.pub
!apt-get update
!apt-get install cuda
!pip install tf-nightly-gpu-2.0-preview`

but when I try to find the version it shows

> 1.13.0-dev20190116

also I have error when I want to use 
the tf.enable_eager_execution() 
and 
NameError: name 'layers' is not defined

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to find which version of TensorFlow is installed in my system?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38549253/how-to-find-which-version-of-tensorflow-is-installed-in-my-system)

Answer (score 1):

Try like this:

```
!pip install tf-nightly-2.0-preview
import tensorflow as tf
```

As explained by [Luca](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54223282/installing-tf-nightly-gpu-2-0-preview-on-google-colab/54223283#54223283) to check the version you need:

```
print(tf.__version__)
```